# Passing variable into sql query in python (sqlite3)

Tags: sql, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm passing a value through into the query via a parameter. The problem is that when running the following code:

```
import sqlite3

def top10(restaurant):
    con = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    t = (restaurant,)
    cur.execute("SELECT * from orchard WHERE CUISINE_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%?%' ORDER BY SCORE;", t)
    return cur.fetchone()
print(top10("thai"))
```

I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
```

I'm not sure how what's triggering it.
Here's what runs successfully when I embed a value called `thai` instead of passing in the variable:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * from orchard WHERE CUISINE_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%thai%' ORDER BY SCORE;")
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
cur.execute("SELECT * from orchard WHERE CUISINE_DESCRIPTION LIKE ? ORDER BY SCORE;", '%'+t+'%')
```

Comment: This worked when making the variable `t = (restaurant,)` to `t = ('%' + restaurant + '%',)` Did not work when doing it in the query as in the snippet though